# Join with multiple table

Tags: mysql

I have three table `professor`,`student` and `pro_stu` where `pro_stu` contain relationship between `professor` and `student` table.

**Professor** (PID, PNAME).

**Student** (SID, SNAME).

**PRO_STU** (PSID, PID, SID).

I want to all student records which student learn from all professor. If you required further information I will give it. I know i have to use join but how to use it I don't know. Thanks.

> **I want student id=11 which name is hasan which learn by all professor.**

I tried following query but no luck

```
SELECT *
FROM student
INNER JOIN pro_stu ON pro_stu.sid=student.sid
INNER JOIN professor ON professor.pid = pro_stu.pid
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7297b/1)

Comment: Downvoted please comment

Comment: Do you just want us to do it for you or are you stuck anywhere?

Comment: I stuck how i join table? please help me do not down vote.

Comment: @Sadikhasan I've not downvoted, but you should prepare some sample data (best in a sqlfiddle) with the desired result. I do not fully understand your problem. It can't be a simple join, of that I'm sure, having had a look at your profile (and I knew some of your good answers anyway).

Comment: Wait I will give sqlfiddle for it

Comment: Provide expected output for your data please

Comment: Downvoted user check my question If it is easy then you can give further down vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe here is what you looking for:

```
SELECT SID, SNAME, count(DISTINCT PID) AS `c` FROM PRO_STU 
INNER JOIN Student USING (SID)
GROUP BY SID, SNAME
HAVING `c` = (SELECT count(*) FROM Professor)
```

Comment: Thanks! I got solution.